# Rails include module throws exception depending where module is included

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to abstract error handling out of my main controllers so I created a module:

```
module Error
  module ErrorHandler

    def self.included(klass)
      klass.class_eval do
       rescue_from StandardError do |e|
         respond(:standard_error, 500, e.to_s)
       end
     end
    end

    def respond
      #...
    end

  end
end
```

And in my `Application` controller I have:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::Cookies
  include Error::ErrorHandler

  before_action :authenticate_request

  attr_reader :current_user

  private

  def authenticate_request
    @current_user = AuthorizeApiRequest.call(cookies[:auth]).result
    render json: { authorized: false }, status: 401 unless @current_user
  end

  def serialize(data, **options)
    Serializer.serialize(data, options)
  end

end
```

Now, if I include the Error::ErrorHandler where it is, I will get either a  name error or method error:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<Users::PerformancesController:0x00007f8f75fda5f0>):

NoMethodError (undefined method `authenticate_request' for #<Users::PerformancesController:0x00007f8f76f40378>):
```

But if I move my include to the bottom of ApplicationController all works fine.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: _Sidenote:_ `ErrorHandler` would not even pass Ruby parser (the opened block has no closing `end`.)

Comment: Good catch. Fixed it.

Comment: Feels like the code in ApplicationController isn't run after the line where you include `ErrorHandler`. Could you check if the execution gets there at all?

Comment: @Darkisa Have you fixed this?